# Гибридная криптография Golang

Tags: golang, криптография, rsa, aes

**Возник вопрос как реализовать гибридную криптографию нативными средствами в Golang.**

Мне нужно защищено обмениваться данными между клиентом и сервером, но для того чтобы бы баланс не в урез производительности и криптографической стойкости, принял решение использовать гибридную криптографию. Но для этого нам нужно по протоколу Диффи Хеллмана сгенерировать и обменятся общим секретным ключем, далее это ключ при помощи AES-128 зашифровать и передать со стороны сервера клиенту или наоборот. Также сгенерировать RSA-2048 ключ и передать при помощи ассиметричного шифрования для дешифровки при помощи симметричного AES и также провести верификацию ключей при помощи RSASSA-PSS.

Пишу протокол для понимания работы компьютерных сетей и базовой криптографии, но не знаю как реализовать потому что нет стандартной поддержки Диффи Хеллмана на эллиптических кривых 25519. А также как это всё соединить воедино, в интернете почитал примеры, но там либо симметричное, либо ассиметричное шифрование.

Прошу помочь с этим вопросом или хотя бы предоставить материалы по этому вопросу, как конкретно на Golang можно это реализовать. Или предоставить минимальный пример в виде кода :) Также возможную схему решения моего вопроса при помощи пояснения какую ЛУЧШЕ конкретно эпилептическую кривую или алгоритм шифрования, верификации использовать для баланса производительности и надежности.

Comment: Для использования в реальных (не учебных) проектах лучше не изобретать велосипедов и просто использовать стандартный TLS, в нём уже реализована такая гибридная криптография

Comment: Ed25519 вам не обязательно использовать. Эта кривая, пожалуй, требуется только в блокчейнах, так как на ней арифметика на 20-30% быстрее чем на эталонных эллиптических кривых, и поэтому меньше нагрузка на CPU при проверке цифровых подписей. У вас же в DH арифметических операций сравнительно немного, любая эллиптическая кривая подойдёт.